# Using a default name for autoplay through jQuery

Tags: jquery, autoplay

I used a free template to set up a jQuery-based multi-gallery photo portfolio site. I'm trying to get the first of three galleries to load by default when someone opens the page. Right now, nothing loads until one of the links for one of the three galleries is pressed.  Prior users had asked the tutorial writer for tips on the same thing, but the only answer forthcoming was:
"you can add auto-play by adding to lines on your script just before (missing word) the on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(‘#default’).click()
});
```

and on your list add a default id on the gallery you want to open as default:
“” yourgalleryname“”
you better type the code instead of copy/paste because different commas come as error on your script"
After many trials, I came to the conclusion that the writer was trying to have me enter code into the .html before a series of commands to jQuery, so I wrote this (the code is after the JavaScript references and before $(function() {. As you can see, I've tried putting in the default: Nature to direct attention to the gallery by that name, but that's apparently not the solution?
I'd appreciate any help I can get on what the correct solution is. I'll admit that I'm not a coder, and there's probably a simple solution, but I've been working on this all night, to no avail.
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('#default').click()
            });
        $(function() {
            //setting a default page
            default: "Nature"
            //caching
            //the main wrapper of the gallery
            var $fp_gallery         = $('#fp_gallery')
            //the overlay when the large image is displayed
            var $fp_overlay         = $('#fp_overlay');
```

In answer to Pete's suggestion:
Pete, it's pretty apparent that I ought to understand better what you're saying, so I appreciate your patience.
I tried your solution, but no dice. Just to be clear: that default: Nature thing before was my attempt to follow instructions I didn't understand. Anyway, here's the code section that I've revised, trying to follow your suggestions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('#Nature').trigger('click');
            });
        $(function() {
            //caching
            //the main wrapper of the gallery
```

Stack Overflow won't let me load the entire code, which was written by the person who wrote the tutorial. It says it's too long. I did see your comment about the missing semicolon, and I can certainly fix it, but the page has been loading and operating properly. Here's as much of the code as I'm permitted:

```
    <!--  JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('#Nature').trigger('click');
            });
        $(function() {
            //caching
            //the main wrapper of the gallery
            var $fp_gallery         = $('#fp_gallery')
            //the overlay when the large image is displayed
            var $fp_overlay         = $('#fp_overlay');
            //image loading status
            var $fp_loading         = $('#fp_loading');
            //the next and previous buttons
            var $fp_next            = $('#fp_next');
            var $fp_prev            = $('#fp_prev');
            //the close button
            var $fp_close           = $('#fp_close');
            //the main container for the thumbs structure
            var $fp_thumbContainer  = $('#fp_thumbContainer');
            //wrapper of jquery ui slider
            var $fp_scrollWrapper   = $('#fp_scrollWrapper');
            //total number of images
            var nmb_images=0;
            //which gallery is clicked (index)
            var gallery_idx=-1;
            //scroller wrapper
            var $fp_thumbScroller   = $('#fp_thumbScroller');
            //jquery ui slider
            var $slider             = $('#slider');
            //the links of the galleries (the cities)
            var $fp_galleries       = $('#fp_galleryList > li');
            //current image being viewed
            var current             = 0;

            //some control flags:
            //prevent fast clicks on next and previous
            var photo_nav           = true;

            //User clicks on a city / gallery;
            $fp_galleries.bind('click',function(){
                $fp_galleries.removeClass('current');
                var $gallery        = $(this);
                $gallery.addClass('current');
                var gallery_index   = $gallery.index();
                if(gallery_idx == gallery_index) return;
                gallery_idx         = gallery_index;
                //close the gallery and slider if opened
                if($fp_thumbContainer.data('opened')==true){
                    $fp_scrollWrapper.fadeOut();
                    $fp_thumbContainer.stop()
                                      .animate({'height':'0px'},200,function(){
                                        openGallery($gallery);
                                      });
                }                 
                else
                    openGallery($gallery);
            });

            //opens a gallery after cliking on a city / gallery
            function openGallery($gallery){
                //current gets reseted
                current             = 0;                  
                //wrapper of each content div, where each image is
                var $fp_content_wrapper = $fp_thumbContainer.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')');
                //hide all the other galleries thumbs wrappers
                $fp_thumbContainer.find('.container').not($fp_content_wrapper).hide();
                //and show this one
                $fp_content_wrapper.show();
                //total number of images
                nmb_images          = $fp_content_wrapper.children('div').length;
                //calculate width,
                //padding left 
                //and padding right for content wrapper
                var w_width     = 0;
                var padding_l   = 0;
                var padding_r   = 0;
                //center of screen
                var center      = $(window).width()/2;
                var one_divs_w  = 0;
                /*
                Note:
                the padding left is the center minus half of the width of the first content div
                the padding right is the center minus half of the width of the last content div
                */
                $fp_content_wrapper.children('div').each(function(i){
                    var $div        = $(this);
                    var div_width   = $div.width(); 
                    w_width         +=div_width;
                    //if first one, lets calculate the padding left
                    if(i==0)
                        padding_l = center - (div_width/2);
                    //if last one, lets calculate the padding right
                    if(i==(nmb_images-1)){
                        padding_r = center - (div_width/2);
                        one_divs_w= div_width;
                    }   
                }).end().css({
                    'width'             : w_width + 'px',
                    'padding-left'      : padding_l + 'px',
                    'padding-right'     : padding_r + 'px'
                });

                //scroll all left;
                $fp_thumbScroller.scrollLeft(w_width);

                //innitialize the slider
                $slider.slider('destroy').slider({
                    orientation : 'horizontal',
                    max         : w_width -one_divs_w,//total width minus one content div width
                    min         : 0,
                    value       : 0,
                    slide       : function(event, ui) {
                        $fp_thumbScroller.scrollLeft(ui.value);
                    },
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        //when we stop sliding 
                        //we may want that the closest picture to the center 
                        //of the window stays centered. Uncomment the following line
                        //if you want that behaviour
                        checkClosest();
                    }
                });
                //open the gallery and show the slider
                $fp_thumbContainer.animate({'height':'240px'},200,function(){
                    $(this).data('opened',true);
                    $fp_scrollWrapper.fadeIn();
                });

                //scroll all right;
                $fp_thumbScroller.stop()
                                 .animate({'scrollLeft':'0px'},2000,'easeInOutExpo');

                //User clicks on a content div (image)
                $fp_content_wrapper.find('.content')
                                 .bind('click',function(e){
                    var $current    = $(this);
                    //track the current one
                    current         = $current.index();
                    //center and show this image
                    //the second parameter set to true means we want to 
                    //display the picture after the image is centered on the screen
                    centerImage($current,true,600);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });                 
            }

            //while the gallery scrolls we want that the slider scrolls as well
            $fp_thumbScroller.scroll(function(){
                $slider.slider('value',parseInt($fp_thumbScroller.scrollLeft(),10));
            });

            //User clicks next button (preview mode)
            $fp_next.bind('click',function(){
                if(photo_nav){
                    photo_nav = false;
                navigate(1);
                }   
            });

            //User clicks previous button (preview mode)
            $fp_prev.bind('click',function(){
                if(photo_nav){
                    photo_nav = false;
                navigate(0);
                }   
            });

            //User clicks next button (thumbs)
            $('#fp_next_thumb').click(function(){
                slideThumb(1);
            });

            //User clicks previous button (thumbs)
            $('#fp_prev_thumb').click(function(){
                slideThumb(0);
            });

            //User clicks close button
            $fp_close.bind('click',function(){
                if(!photo_nav) return;
                //windows scroll if any
                var windowS         = $(window).scrollTop();
                //the large image being viewed
                var $large_img      = $('#fp_preview');
                //the current thumb
                var $current        = $fp_thumbScroller.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')')
                                                       .find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(current+1)+')');
                //offset values of current thumb
                var current_offset  = $current.offset();
                //the large image will animate in the direction of the center
                //after that it is removed from the DOM
                $large_img.stop().animate({
                    'top'           : current_offset.top + windowS + 'px',
                    'left'          : $(window).width()/2 - $current.width()/2 + 'px',
                    'width'         : $current.width() + 'px',
                    'height'        : $current.height() + 'px',
                    'opacity'       : 0
                },800,function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                //hide the overlay, and the next, previous and close buttons
                hidePreviewFunctions();
            });


            });

            //centers an image and opens it if open is true
            function centerImage($obj,open,speed){
                //the offset left of the element
                var obj_left            = $obj.offset().left;
                //the center of the element is its offset left plus 
                //half of its width
                var obj_center          = obj_left + ($obj.width()/2);
                //the center of the window
                var center              = $(window).width()/2;
                //how much the scroller has scrolled already
                var currentScrollLeft   = parseFloat($fp_thumbScroller.scrollLeft(),10);
                //so we know that in order to center the image,
                //we must scroll the center of the image minus the center of the screen,
                //and add whatever we have scrolled already
                var move                = currentScrollLeft + (obj_center - center);
                if(move != $fp_thumbScroller.scrollLeft()) //try 'easeInOutExpo'
                    $fp_thumbScroller.stop()
                                     .animate({scrollLeft: move}, speed,function(){
                        if(open)
                            enlarge($obj);
                    });
                else if(open)
                    enlarge($obj);
            }

            //shows the large image
            //first we position the large image on top of the thumb
            //and then, we animate it to the maximum we can get 
            //based on the windows size
            function enlarge($obj){
                //the image element
                var $thumb = $obj.find('img');
                //show loading image
                $fp_loading.show();
                //preload large image
                $('<img id="fp_preview" />').load(function(){
                    var $large_img  = $(this);

                    //confirm there's no other large one
                    $('#fp_preview').remove();

                    $large_img.addClass('fp_preview');
                    //now let's position this image on the top of the thumb
                    //we append this image to the fp_gallery div
                    var obj_offset  = $obj.offset();
                    $large_img.css({
                        'width' : $thumb.width() + 'px',
                        'height': $thumb.height() + 'px',
                        'top'   : obj_offset.top + 'px',
                        'left'  : obj_offset.left + 5 + 'px'//5 of margin
                    }).appendTo($fp_gallery);
                    //getFinalValues gives us the maximum possible width and height
                    //for the large image based on the windows size.
                    //those values are saved on the element using the jQuery.data()
                    getFinalValues($large_img);
                    var largeW  = $large_img.data('width');
                    var largeH  = $large_img.data('height');
                    //windows width, height and scroll
                    var $window = $(window);
                    var windowW = $window.width();
                    var windowH = $window.height();
                    var windowS = $window.scrollTop();
                    //hide the image loading
                    $fp_loading.hide();
                    //show the overlay
                    $fp_overlay.show();
                    //now animate the large image
                    $large_img.stop().animate({
                        'top'       : windowH/2 -largeH/2 + windowS + 'px',
                        'left'      : windowW/2 -largeW/2 + 'px',
                        'width'     : largeW + 'px',
                        'height'    : largeH + 'px',
                        'opacity'   : 1
                    },800,function(){
                        //after the animation, 
                        //show the next, previous and close buttons
                        showPreviewFunctions();
                    });
                }).attr('src',$thumb.attr('alt'));
            }

            //shows next or previous image
            //1 is right;0 is left
            function navigate(way){
                //show loading image
                $fp_loading.show();
                if(way==1){
                    ++current;
                    var $current = $fp_thumbScroller.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')')
                                                    .find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(current+1)+')');
                    if($current.length == 0){
                        --current;
                        $fp_loading.hide();
                        photo_nav = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    --current;
                    var $current = $fp_thumbScroller.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')')
                                                    .find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(current+1)+')');
                    if($current.length == 0){
                        ++current;
                        $fp_loading.hide();
                        photo_nav = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                //load large image of next/previous content div
                $('<img id="fp_preview" />').load(function(){
                    $fp_loading.hide();
                    var $large_img      = $(this);
                    var $fp_preview     = $('#fp_preview');

                    //make the current one slide left if clicking next
                    //make the current one slide right if clicking previous
                    var animate_to      = -$fp_preview.width();
                    var animate_from    = $(window).width();
                    if(way==0){
                        animate_to      = $(window).width();
                        animate_from    = -$fp_preview.width();
                    }

                    //now we want that the thumb (of the last image viewed) 
                    //stays centered on the screen
                    centerImage($current,false,1000);

                    $fp_preview.stop().animate({'left':animate_to+'px'},500,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                        $large_img.addClass('fp_preview');
                        getFinalValues($large_img);
                        var largeW  = $large_img.data('width');
                        var largeH  = $large_img.data('height');
                        var $window = $(window);
                        var windowW = $window.width();
                        var windowH = $window.height();
                        var windowS = $window.scrollTop();
                        $large_img.css({
                            'width' : largeW+'px',
                            'height': largeH+'px',
                            'top'   : windowH/2 -largeH/2 + windowS + 'px',
                            'left'      : animate_from + 'px',
                            'opacity'   : 1 
                        }).appendTo($fp_gallery)
                          .stop()
                          .animate({'left':windowW/2 -largeW/2+'px'},500,function(){photo_nav = true;});
                    });
                }).attr('src',$current.find('img').attr('alt'));    
            }

            //show the next, previous and close buttons
            function showPreviewFunctions(){
                $fp_next.stop().animate({'right':'0px'},500);
                $fp_prev.stop().animate({'left':'0px'},500);
                $fp_close.show();
            }

            //hide the overlay, and the next, previous and close buttons
            function hidePreviewFunctions(){
                $fp_next.stop().animate({'right':'-50px'},500);
                $fp_prev.stop().animate({'left':'-50px'},500);
                $fp_close.hide();
                $fp_overlay.hide();
            }

            function getFinalValues($image){
                var widthMargin     = 0
                var heightMargin    = 20;
                var $window         = $(window);
                var windowH         = $window.height()-heightMargin;
                var windowW         = $window.width()-widthMargin;
                var theImage     = new Image();
                theImage.src     = $image.attr("src");
                var imgwidth     = theImage.width;
                var imgheight    = theImage.height;

                if((imgwidth > windowW)||(imgheight > windowH)){
                    if(imgwidth > imgheight){
                        var newwidth = windowW;
                        var ratio = imgwidth / windowW;
                        var newheight = imgheight / ratio;
                        theImage.height = newheight;
                        theImage.width= newwidth;
                        if(newheight>windowH){
                            var newnewheight = windowH;
                            var newratio = newheight/windowH;
                            var newnewwidth =newwidth/newratio;
                            theImage.width = newnewwidth;
                            theImage.height= newnewheight;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        var newheight = windowH;
                        var ratio = imgheight / windowH;
                        var newwidth = imgwidth / ratio;
                        theImage.height = newheight;
                        theImage.width= newwidth;
                        if(newwidth>windowW){
                            var newnewwidth = windowW;
                            var newratio = newwidth/windowW;
                            var newnewheight =newheight/newratio;
                            theImage.height = newnewheight;
                            theImage.width= newnewwidth;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $image.data('width',theImage.width);
                $image.data('height',theImage.height);
            }

            //slides the scroller one picture 
            //to the right or left
            function slideThumb(way){
                if(way==1){
                    ++current;
                    var $next = $fp_thumbScroller.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')')
                                                 .find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(current+1)+')');
                    if($next.length > 0)
                        centerImage($next,false,600);
                    else{
                        --current;
                        return;
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    --current;
                    var $prev = $fp_thumbScroller.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')')
                                                 .find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(current+1)+')');
                    if($prev.length > 0)
                        centerImage($prev,false,600);
                    else{
                        ++current;
                        return;
                    }   
                }                   
            }

            //when we stop sliding 
            //we may want that the closest picture to the center 
            //of the window stays centered
            function checkClosest(){
                var center              = $(window).width()/2;
                var current_distance    = 99999999;
                var idx                 = 0;    
                $container              = $fp_thumbScroller.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')');
                $container.find('.content').each(function(i){
                    var $obj        = $(this);
                    //the offset left of the element
                    var obj_left    = $obj.offset().left;
                    //the center of the element is its offset left plus 
                    //half of its width
                    var obj_center  = obj_left + ($obj.width()/2);
                    var distance    = Math.abs(center-obj_center);
                    if(distance < current_distance){
                        current_distance    = distance;
                        idx                 = i;
                    }   
                });
                var $new_current    = $container.find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(idx+1)+')');
                current             = $new_current.index();
                centerImage($new_current,false,200);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: try  $('#default').trigger('click')

Answer (score 0):

A C-Link says you can try the line:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#default').trigger('click');
});
```

But you should be clear that the word '#default' above refers to the name of the id of your gallery object. I.e. if your gallery div has the id 'nature' then you should change this line to:

```
$('#nature').trigger('click');
```

or

```
$('#nature').click();
```

Do check the code you are typing above as your second block contains two mistakes:

```
default: nature
```

Will do nothing but break and:

```
 var $fp_gallery         = $('#fp_gallery')
```

Is missing a semicolon (;) at the end.

Also, the apostrophes in your examples may cause issues as they are the curly ones found in word processors. Try to do editing in a plain text editor to avoid this and just use the straight ones.

If you post your full code for the solution here I can try to advise if it is correct or not. Or you can use http://www.jshint.com/ to report issues to you directly.

Comment: Pete,
Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'll post the whole code in a second, but first, as to the section we've been talking about: 
I have now entered both of the solutions that you've suggested. Length restrictions on this window don't allow me to paste all the code, so I'll follow up in the "New Answer" section and hope that gets through

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. All the links work fine. The problem is to get one of the sliders to load automatically. I don't care that much which one it is, although I think Nature would be best. Since I'd made such a hash of my original question and nobody was answering, I went ahead and resubmitted it, including your proposed solution from yesterday. The link to that is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933965/automatically-triggering-a-link-without-a-clear-default-id

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to this problem probably is in that opening section that identifies the galleries:

I've never before seen web code that is so flexible, letting me establish new galleries, give them new names in only one place without duplicating them with additional instructions elsewhere, etc. It's kind of a nifty thing, but also cryptic, because it makes it tough to designate the gallery link for clicking.

```
        <ul id="fp_galleryList" class="fp_galleryList">
            <li>Nature</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Features</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fp_thumbContainer">
            <div id="fp_thumbScroller">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div><a href="#"><img src="Thumbnails/Nature/05.scan.1101.ks_high.jpg" alt="Photos/KenNature/05.scan.1101.ks.jpg" class="thumb" /></a></div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, my nephew, an internet company exec, figured out the solution. This made it work:

If you replace the  tag in your test page with this:

```
<body onload = "javascript:$('li' ).first().click();">
```

it will work.

Sure enough, it did.